# Emmet в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, emmet

Когда пишешь сокращения, к примеру: a.icon-basket, в итоге получается примерно такой код:

```
<a href="#" class="icon-basket">Корзина</a>
```

Возможно ли настроить Emmet так, чтобы в начале всегда шел атрибут class="", а потом уже остальные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.class-name[style=height:1px;]` даст результат после нажатия на `tab` `<a href="" class="class-name" style="height : 1px;"></a>`.

`Emmet` будет писать тег аттрибуты по такой череде, которую Вы указали.

Проверено на примере в [PHPStom 2016.2.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если даже написать атрибуты по очереди, то почему то все равно порядок нарушается. Пишем: a.icon-basket[href="#"], получаем <a href="#" class="icon-basket"></a>

Comment: @Марсель, у плагина есть свои надстройки на счёт порядка построения.

Comment: изменить их невозможно?

Comment: @Марсель, можно

Comment: не подскажете как?

Comment: @Марсель, в официальной документации есть примеры кастомных настроек http://docs.emmet.io/customization/

Answer (score 1):

Я сделала так: В Sublime Text редакторе открыла `Preferences > Package settings > Emmet > Settings - User` (также файл лежит в `c:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\`)
Там нашла объект `"snippets"`, и в `"html"` прописала нужные мне свойства нужного элемента. 
Я хотела решить ту же проблему, что у вас. Получилось так:

```
    "snippets": {
    "html": {
        // "filters": "html, bem",
        "abbreviations": {
            "example": "<div class='example1' title='Custom element example'>",
            "a": "<a class=\"\" href=\"\">"
        }
    }
},
```